# counting different web pages in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

There is a iframe in html:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.wikipedia.org/" frameBorder="0" width="1000px" height="700px"></iframe>
```

and also jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body', $('#frame')).contents().find('a').click(function(event) {
      alert("Link Clicked");//not work
    });
});
```

How to do, clicking in iframe's wikipedia different links, it says link clicked?

thanks

Comment: You can't access the document loaded in an iFrame, unless it's part of the same domain.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid same origin rules apply to IFRAME's as well as XHR requests.

If you are not familiar with Same-Origin then have a read here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy